# How to make a 'log' function work so that only log("The log message") would work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do it for a while now, and I really have no clue anymore. What I want basically is to do a function to log so it would work as simply as log("{the log message}")

It doesn't have to be a method, just a simplified way to log messages so it would be easier to read.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
# file one



from functions import *
try:
    open('key.txt', "r")
    key = True
except FileNotFoundError:
    key = False

if check_internet():
    x = status_boot[0]
elif not check_internet():
    x = status_boot[1]

log("Hi")




# file two




from datetime import datetime

import requests

status_boot = ["online", "offline", "key invalid", "error", "Error: Key not accessible!"]

x = status_boot[3]


def time():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


def check_internet():
    url = 'http://www.google.com/'
    timeout = 5
    try:
        _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return False


def log(m):
    write = open('archerlog.txt', 'w+')
    return write.write(f"[{time}] {m}")
```

Comment: Where are the problems in your code?

Comment: I think you want () after ‘time’ in your log function

Comment: Wow, I'm actually stupid. You are right. Thank you! This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

file one (not changed)

```
from functions import *
try:
    open('key.txt', "r")
    key = True
except FileNotFoundError:
    key = False

if check_internet():
    x = status_boot[0]
elif not check_internet():
    x = status_boot[1]

log("Hi")
```

file two

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests

status_boot = ["online", "offline", "key invalid", "error", "Error: Key not accessible!"]

x = status_boot[3]


def time():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


def check_internet():
    url = 'http://www.google.com/'
    timeout = 5
    try:
        _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return False


def log(m):
    write = open('archerlog.txt', 'w+')
    return write.write(f"[{time()}] {m}") # add ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the `time()` function for it to return `now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`
Change your `log()` function with this:

```
def log(m):
    write = open('archerlog.txt', 'w+')
    return write.write(f"[{time()}] {m}")
```